# emacs - long line hightlight color too dark

Tags: emacs, whitespace

I use below code to highlight characters longer than 78.

```
(setq whitespace-style '(face empty tabs lines-tail trailing))
(setq whitespace-line-column 78)
(global-whitespace-mode 1)
```

It works fine but the background color too dark!
[image]

How can I change the highlight characters background color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just customize the `whitespace-line` face.

Answer (score 0):

just like below:

```
(setq whitespace-style '(face empty tabs lines-tail trailing))
(setq whitespace-line-column 78)
(global-whitespace-mode 1)

(custom-set-faces
  '(whitespace-line ((t (:background "#eff0f1"))))
```